# Custom Node.js Caching Solution is getting Garbage Collected

Tags: node.js, express, caching

I have written a basic in-memory caching solution in node.js:

```
import { log } from "console";

export class cache {
    cacheTime: number = 604800;
    cacheCheck: number = 259200000;
    cache: { [x: string]: any; } = {};
    cacheTimestamp: { [x: string]: number; } = {};
    keys: string[] = [];

    constructor() {
        setInterval(() => {
            log('Attempting to clear expired cache!');
            try {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.keys.length; i++) {
                    if (this.cacheTimestamp[this.keys[i]] <= (Date.now() / 1000) - this.cacheTime) {
                        delete this.cache[this.keys[i]];
                        delete this.cacheTimestamp[this.keys[i]];
                        this.keys.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                log('Failed!');
            }
        }, this.cacheCheck);
    }

    public addCache(key: string, data: any) {
        this.cache[key] = data;
        this.cacheTimestamp[key] = Date.now() / 1000;
        this.keys.push(key);
    }

    public getCache(key: string) {
        try {
            this.cacheTimestamp[key] = Date.now() / 1000;
            return this.cache[key];
        } catch {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented it to serve static files on an express files (I am unable to use nginx or apache) and as such made this. However, the cached data gets garbage collected, and as such, the cache is only useful if a request to the same file is made within a few minutes of the addition of the file in the cache, sometimes even seconds. How do I fix this?